# Spring / Hibernate: Dubious NPE while iniitializing SessionFactory

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

While loading the spring application context, I am getting a NPE relating to the hibernate-session-factory.

But I really have no idea, what the cause is? 

Does any body has any idea where to *start searching*?

The relevant bean-definition is

```
<bean id="mySessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
        [...]
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${db.hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${db.hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${db.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The stacktrace is here: http://pastebin.com/8VB8zYGb

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The usual rule of thumb (not specific to the exception you give) is: remove from Hibernate the entities you have defined until you get no errors. Once you get the entity that is giving you trouble, remove attributes until you get no errors.

Comment: @SJuan76 Thanks. I got the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the problem was, that I forgot to annotate an abstract super-class of some entities and I have used fields from that un-annotated super-class in an entity.

I found the problem using the way described by SJuan76.